# Google Fit: activity minutes vs. move minutes

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I get "activity minutes" with

```
final DataReadRequest readRequest =
    new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT,
                   DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

and "move minutes" with

```
final DataReadRequest readRequest3 =
    new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES,
                   DataType.AGGREGATE_MOVE_MINUTES)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

My understanding of the difference is, that any activity counts against "activity minutes", even if standing still, like weight-lifting, and any activity, where the location changes, counts against "move minutes", like bicycling.

That would mean, that "activity minutes" are always equal to or greater than "move minutes".

However, my observations show the opposite, e.g.

```
44 activity minutes
48 move minutes
```

How can that be? Am I doing something wrong, coding-wise?

Comment: I think the reason was found in the documentation. If you say [move minutes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES), it is counting each data during the [active minutes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)(whatever you are doing) and the activity minutes sets only when you are doing a [fitness activity](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities).

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0: Thanks for your explanation (and of course I have read the documentation :-) ), but I cannot follow your reasoning. Can you give me one example, where I score, say, 10 move minutes, but at the same time less than 10 activity minutes?

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion about this?

Comment: @TimM: No. Unfortunately, Google gives no concrete explanations about what these terms mean, just fuzzy ones :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anything categorized as vigorous intensity is scored as 2 move mins therefore a 5 minute activity can net 10 move mins. In your example a couple of the mins were scored x2. If you click https://support.google.com/fit/answer/7619539?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Chow-to-earn-heart-points%2Cbased-on-your-heart-rate they define double points as any exercise over 70% of your max heart rate.